# Baud rate of IP network

Tags: ip, baud-rate

Since all the devices on the internet talks without a presetting of the baud rate, it seems all of them should have the same baud rate. If so what is the baud rate of devices communicating over internet protocol?

Comment: False. They don't all talk at the same speed, but that's what memory buffers and retransmission is for. Baud rate is basically the same concept as bandwidth, and it should be fairly obvious that not everything on the Internet has the same bandwidth.

Comment: Aside from being off-topic, your question makes no sense for the Internet as a whole, since transmission speeds vary from link to link.

Comment: The reason for this question was I am implementing a protocol specific router where on one side I had IP network and other side a slower MSTP (Master Slave Token Passing) network.  So I should decide the caching capabilities required for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Protocol (IP) is at the Network layer in the OSI model.  Concerns about physical transmission (such as baud rate) would be considered in the Physical and Data Link layers.

A more general question of: "How does IP manage across heterogeneous physical connections with differing speeds" is roughly:  It doesn't, flow control happens at higher layers of the protocol, such as TCP.

Comment: Probably the best answer one can get to such a daft question. Unfortunately, it's more difficult to remove a daft and off-topic question once it has an answer :(